# How to download the PDF file after uploading to the Firebase storage, and show in the Flutter application and keep it always static

Tags: firebase, pdf, firebase-storage

How to  download the pdf after uploading to the firebase storage, and show in the flutter application and keep it always static.

I mean when ever user visits that flutter page or screen in the application, the pdf file downloaded should be opened on a click eventon a icon or image etc. It should not disappear after closing the application, when we open the application for the second time.

User should be able to download and view or open the PDF whenever he wish.

This is my code I have tried as below:

```
uploadToFirebase() {
    if (_multiPick) {
        _paths.forEach((fileName, filePath) => {upload(fileName, filePath)});
    } else {
        String fileName = _path.split('/').last;
        String filePath = _path;
        upload(fileName, filePath);
    }
}
 
upload(fileName, filePath) {
    _extension = fileName.toString().split('.').last;
    StorageReference storageRef =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileName);
    final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(
        File(filePath),
        StorageMetadata(
        contentType: '$_pickType/$_extension',
        ),
    );
    setState(() {
        _tasks.add(uploadTask);
    });
}

Future<void> downloadFile(StorageReference ref) async {
    final String url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    final http.Response downloadData = await http.get(url);
    final Directory systemTempDir = Directory.systemTemp;
    final File tempFile = File('${systemTempDir.path}/tmp.jpg');
    if (tempFile.existsSync()) {
      await tempFile.delete();
    }
    await tempFile.create();
    final StorageFileDownloadTask task = ref.writeToFile(tempFile);
    final int byteCount = (await task.future).totalByteCount;
    var bodyBytes = downloadData.bodyBytes;
    final String name = await ref.getName();
    final String path = await ref.getPath();
    print(
      'Success!\nDownloaded $name \nUrl: $url'
      '\npath: $path \nBytes Count :: $byteCount',
    );
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        content: Image.memory(
          bodyBytes,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
      ),
    );
}
```

This code only uploads pdf file but do not download and show pdf where as it is uploading image and downloading, showing image files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Finally I have successfully downloaded the pdf file  after uploading it to firebase storage in this way

```
    `void  filePicker(BuildContext context) async {
    try {


        PDfFile1 = await FilePicker.getFile(type: FileType.custom, allowedExtensions: ['pdf']);
        fileName = p.basename(PDfFile1.path);
        setState(() {
          fileName = p.basename(PDfFile1.path);
          isPDF_selected=true;
        });
        print(fileName);
       // _uploadFile(PDfFile1, fileName);


    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Sorry...'),
              content: Text('Unsupported exception: $e'),
              actions: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  child: Text('OK'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                )
              ],
            );
          }
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> _uploadFile(File PDFFile1, String filename) async {

    if (FileType == 'pdf') {



  PDfFile1 = await FilePicker.getFile(type: FileType.custom, allowedExtensions: ['pdf']);
  fileName = p.basename(PDfFile1.path);
  setState(() {
  fileName = p.basename(PDfFile1.path);
  isPDF_selected=true;
  });
  print(fileName);
 // _uploadFile(PDfFile1, fileName);
    }
    final FirebaseStorage _storage4 =
    FirebaseStorage(storageBucket: 'gs://flutter-cb66a.appspot.com');

    //StorageUploadTask uploadTask4;
    String PDFPath = 'DeviceDocs/DeviceDocs${DateTime.now()}.pdf';
   final StorageReference  _storagepdfreference   = FirebaseStorage().ref().child(PDFPath);


     StorageUploadTask uploadTask4 = _storagepdfreference.putFile(PDfFile1);
     StorageTaskSnapshot downloadPDFUrl = (await uploadTask4.onComplete);
     String url = (await downloadPDFUrl.ref.getDownloadURL());
    print("URL is $url");
    setState(() {
      uploadTask4 = _storage4.ref().child('DeviceDocs/DeviceDocs${DateTime.now()}.pdf').putFile(PDfFile1);
      _PDFUploaded= true;
    });
  }

  Future downloadPDfFile1() async {
    String downloadAddress= await _storagepdfreference.getDownloadURL();
    setState(() {
      _downloadPDFUrl= downloadAddress;
    });
  }
`
```

But Now I want to open  the pdf directly from the pdfUrl. How to do so ?